# Skipping Android Layouts xml resource

Tags: java, android, xml

When developing for the android. Are we bound to using xml layout files? (In res\layout )
Or can we skip them entirely and programmatically create and implement our layouts for UI?

Comment: Yes, you can programmatically create views

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.
In an `Activity` you can use `setContentView(View view)` instead of `setContentView(int resource)` in the `onCreate()` callback.
If you use a `Fragment` you can programmatically create a `View` instead of inflating a resource. This has to be done in the `onCreateView()` callback of the fragment

Comment: So, to clarify, we could even delete the layout.xml file and then go about our business with no issues what so ever?